# Playing many audio files off the same audio element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a web page to preview songs letting the viewing public listen to a snippet of each song.

What i dont want to do is reinvent the wheel by creating many calls to many audio elements, you can see how I use "sample" as the first but i don't wanna keep repeating code over and over again.

Here's how it currently works:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <audio id="sample" src="BACKING unforgettable fire.mp3" controls preload>
                <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
            </audio>
        </div>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:playSegment(10, 35);">BACKING unforgettable fire - <img src="http://www.auctioneerslive.co.uk/music/play.png"></a>
        <script>
            var audio = document.getElementById('sample');
            var segmentEnd;
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
                if (segmentEnd && audio.currentTime >= segmentEnd){
                    audio.pause();
                }
                console.log(audio.currentTime);
            }, false);
            function playSegment(startTime, endTime){
                segmentEnd = endTime;
                audio.currentTime = startTime;
                audio.play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the URL of the MP3 file to the playSegment() call in your `<a>` tags, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:playSegment('BACKING unforgettable fire.mp3', 10, 35);">BACKING unforgettable fire - <img src="play.png"></a>
```

Then modify your playSegment() function as follows:

```
function playSegment(fileURL, startTime, endTime){
    audio.src = fileURL;
    audio.oncanplay = function(){
            segmentEnd = endTime;
            audio.currentTime = startTime;    
            audio.play();
    };
    audio.load();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for info, it doesn't seem to play now making those changes

Comment: I've updated my answer with a correction, please check it and try with that code.

Comment: it is still linking with the getElementByID('sample') - if I take this out it doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question but yet, it needs to use the the audio tag with ID "sample" to work. However, you only need this one and only audio tag (no need to repeat it), so to add more links to play other audio samples, just repeat the `<a>` tags that when clicked run the `playSegment()` function passing the URL of the MP3 file, the start time, and end time.

Comment: The above code does'nt work if you look at 

var audio = document.getElementById('sample');
your audio.src = fileURL does'nt do anything

Comment: Could you alter all mine above and i will check that please?

Comment: Hold on... got it working but doesn't end where it should

Answer (score 0):

View tweaks but sorted, thanks ablopez

```
function playSegment2(fileURL, startTime, endTime)
{
    var audio = document.getElementById('sample');
    var segmentEnd;

    audio.src = fileURL;
    audio.oncanplay = function()
    {
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function ()
        {   
            if (segmentEnd && audio.currentTime >= segmentEnd) 
            {
                audio.pause();
            } 
            console.log(audio.currentTime);

        }, false);
        segmentEnd = endTime;
        audio.currentTime = startTime;    
        audio.play();        
    };
    audio.load();
}
```